# Creating advanced Healthbar Texture for Game UI

Tags: interface-design, games

I'm pretty new to this all, especially Game UI Design and I would like to know how to create a realy good looking Healthbar.

I should perhaps mention that, since I'm so new to this, I don't have Photoshop or any of the other paid Tools!

Here is an example from DeviantArt where somebody created a Bar like I would like to.

[image]

Comment: well first of all Welcome to GD SE ; i'm professionally game designer and since you want some brief details i'm commenting instead of answering; if you are new you can go with inkscape and gimp; both are free and supports many features; im not used to use above softs since i have photoshop and illustrator but even with gimp you can do a lot more; and about design; it always depends on theme and if you want to use photoshop you can get free trial of it :) have fun in community . i'll provide further instructions once you get clear about your software since if it photoshop then i can help a lot

Comment: What do you expect as an answer? The question is really vague and 'a really good looking' something is a subjective statement. If you don't have any experience with software maybe it's a good idea to learn some software first?

Comment: @Design Phoenix thanks for the comment and I think I will go with gimp xD

Comment: @Sergey I know that good looking isn't rly a good description, thats why I added the link for the picture. Concerning learning the software first: Probably a good idea. I will look for some nice tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You could use GIMP (which is free) to create such a texture. No need to buy anything! Since you have no experience, here's a very simple method:

1. Open a new image in GIMP using *File > New*, and set the image size to the size of the health bar you want.
2. Click *Filters > Render > Noise > Solid Noise*. Deselect the link icon to break the aspect ratio. This is located to the right of the X and Y size sliders. Adjust the X, Y and Detail sliders until you get a texture you like. For example:

[image]

3. Click *Colors > Colorize* and choose a nice bright colour:

[image]

4. Click *Layer > New Layer*, choose transparency as the fill colour
5. Select a bright contrasting colour as the foreground colour (I chose a bright blue shown below)
6. With the Gradient Tool, click and drag to make a Foreground to Transparent gradient. You can choose this option in the gradient dialog which is shown as *FG (t)* in the example below

[image]

7. Finally set the layer blending Mode in the layers panel to Value (HSV). This will allow more of the texture detail to show through the blue overlay.

[image]

Comment: You're too nice

Comment: Thanks for the answer that really helped me a lot. And I think I have to thank you for replacing the link with the actual picture as well so thank you :)

Comment: @ZachSaucier - well, we were all newbies once upon a time!